# What is the purpose of the rho environment argument in R?

Tags: r

As explained [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html), when an internal or primitive function is called, its last argument is `rho`, the environment in which the call was executed.

On the other hand, we have `R_GlobalContext->sysparent` — this is what the `environment()` returns in R. The `sysparent` field is described as

```
/* Evaluation Context Structure */
typedef struct RCNTXT {
    ...
    SEXP sysparent;     /* environment the closure was called from */
    ...
}
```

It seems that the meaning of `rho` and `sysparent` is the same.

Thus, my questions are:

1. If they are the always the same, why bother to pass the `rho` argument?
2. If they are not the same, how/when do they differ?
3. If I am inside a `.Call` function, how do I get hold of `rho` to call internal R functions, short of passing it from the R wrapper?